# Can't mutate [Int] using .remove(at:)

Tags: swift

```
var bigNum = [2,34,5].remove(at: 2)
```

Error:

> Playground execution failed: error: CalculatorPlayGround.playground:35:14: error: cannot use mutating member on immutable value of type '[Int]'
>   var bigNum = [2,34,5].remove(at: 2)

But

```
var bigNum = [2,34,5]
var b = bigNum.remove(at: 2)
```

is ok.

What is the difference? Why does it work in the second case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.remove(at:)` tries to **mutate** the array you call it on.

When you create the array like you did in your first example (`[1,2,3].whatever`), it creates an immutable **`constant`**, as if you were to create it like this:

```
let array = [2, 34, 5] //not mutable
```

If you force it to create the array as a variable, it *is* mutable:

```
var array = [2, 34, 5] //mutable
```

**Note**

I don't know exactly what you are trying to do, but `bigNum` makes me assume you're trying to get a number from the array? Because right now, `bigNum` would become this array: `[2, 34]` instead of just a number.

Answer (score 1):

`[2,34,5]` in itself is a *literal*, and as such is immutable in Swift (i.e. you can't write `[2,34,5].remove(at: 2)`). To apply a mutating function, you first need to store your array in a mutable container, using the `var` keyword:

```
var bigNum = [2,34,5]
```

Only after doing so, you can use mutating func [`.remove(at:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1641390-remove) on mutable `bigNum`.